# My statistics aren't matching to the specific youtube channel ID

Tags: python, pandas, youtube-api

I made a second API call which consists of the statistics of the youtube channels ids i received from my first API call and i inserted it into the for loop i had initially made in order to organize the data from my first API call. Here is the code :

```
#collecting snippet data
for video in response['items']:
    if video['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video": 
        video_id = video['id']['videoId']
        video_title = video['snippet']['title']
        video_description = video['snippet']['description']
        channel_title = video['snippet']['channelTitle']
        date_upload = video['snippet']['publishedAt']
        date_upload = str(date_upload).split('T')[0]   


#collecting statistics data
    #2nd API CALL
    video_stats_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?   part=statistics&key="+API_KEY

        video_ids = ['xC-c7E5PK0Y',
        'X3paOmcrTjQ',
        '-ETQ97mXXF0',
        'FvGRKQipTP8',
        'LHBE6Q9XlzI',
        ]
    for vid in video_ids:
        video_stats_url += "&id=" + vid

    response_2 = requests.get(video_stats_url).json()
    
     
    view_count = response_2['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
    like_count = response_2['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
    favorite_count = response_2['items'][0]['statistics']['favoriteCount']
    comment_count = response_2['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount']
```

Then after this code, i saved it into a pandas dataframe

I was hoping each unique statistics from the 2nd API call will be applied into the DataFrame, which contains, like_count, view_count, favorite_count and comment_count. However, i see duplicates values of those features applied in other rows. Here's a look showing different youtube channels with identical views, likes and comment counts. I know having [0] in the statistics variable is the problem, but when i remove it, i get an error. Thank you.

Please help, i'm a newbie to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing your response_2 data to see if any of these fields are present in your data

You can also use the get method, and if you can't get it, you can just call it None. Like this, you can guarantee that your program won't fail because of missing fields, but you should do something if you get None.

```py
like_count = response_2.get('items', [{}])[0].get('statistics', {}).get('likeCount', None)
```

Or you can use a try to catch exceptions directly.

My advice is to look at the json data returned by your response_2 for analysis, as the format of the data returned by the interface should not theoretically change much.